# 2 floating divs on top of 2 centered divs

Tags: css, image, html

I'm trying to create something that will allow me to put something on top of images in this case, small images.

basically, it goes like this and both main divs are centered:

http://jsmith.elementfx.com/images/questions.png

tia.

Sorry, here is

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"><a href=""><img src="" width="130" height="130" style="border:2px solid #72d6fe" /></a></div>
     <div id="leftimage"><h2>963</h2></div>         
     <div id="right"><a href=""><img src="" width="130" height="130" style="border:2px solid #72d6fe" /></a></div>
     <div id="rightimage"><h2>434</h2></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:320px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:20px;
    position:relative;      
}

#leftimage{
    position:absolute;
    padding-top:2px;
    margin-left:5px;
    width:65px;
}

#right {
    margin-right:15px;
}

#rightimage{
    position:absolute;
    padding-top:2px;
    width:65px;
}
```

Comment: You should post some code to show us what you have tried until now.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: use background property in css of that div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `z-index` and `position` to acheive it,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bV253/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"><a href=""><img src="" width="130" height="130" style="border:2px solid #72d6fe" /></a></div>
     <div id="leftimage"><h2>963</h2></div>         
     <div id="right"><div id="rightimage"><h2>434</h2></div><a href=""><img src="" width="130" height="130" style="border:2px solid #72d6fe" /></a></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:320px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#left {
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right:20px;
    position:relative;      
}

#leftimage{
    position:absolute;
    padding-top:2px;
    margin-left:5px;
    width:65px;
    z-index:1;
}

#right {
  position:relative;
    margin-right:15px;
}

#rightimage{

     margin-left:175px;
   position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sajad.  This worked out perfectly.  I'm still not understanding what Z-Index is all about...why 1 or 1000?

Comment: @user3367787:you can give 1 instaed of 1000 there,it doesn't matter,we just needs to give z-index to put the div over another

Comment: @user3367787:accept it if it worked out perfectly for you,and you are welcome for more doubts

Comment: @user3367787:do you know how to accept an answer,by clicking the green arrow to the left of the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

use this code, the calculation of the width and height of images would be according to your images:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="img1">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/test_tube.png" width="32" height="32" />
    </div>
    <div class="img2">
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/test_tube.png" width="32" height="32" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    width:270px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.img1,.img2{
    width:128px;
    height:128px;
    background:url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/test_tube.png);
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.img2{margin:0;}
```

[DEMO jsfiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/PYSmr/)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo Fiddle - Quad view with 3 layered images](http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/yvhRS/embedded/result/)

[image: Screenshot of demo fiddle]

```
<div class="container start">

    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/300/555555"></img>

    <div id="base1" class="base">

        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200/654321"></img>

        <div id="overlay1" class="overlay">

            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100/123456"></img>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

---

```
.base {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: -290px;
    left: 10px;
}

.overlay {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: -190px;
}

.container {
    left:100px; 
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.start {
    clear: left;
}
```